# Focus on textbox after jquery modal dialog close

Tags: jquery-ui, focus, modal-dialog

I have a problem with jquery modal dialog. I have focus evant on textbox (clasic javascript), it's work fine when the page is reloaded . But I'm trying to find out how to set focus after modal dialog close. Is there somebody who will be able to give me an answer?

html

```
<div>
<form action='core/php/_scr_commission_equipment_direct_add.php?token=$token' method='post' name='equipmentIDN_form'>
IDN <input type='text' class='idn_reader_text_color' name='equipmentIDN_direct' autocomplete='off' />
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.equipmentIDN_form.equipmentIDN_direct.focus()
</script>
```

jquery

```
$('#dialog-graph2').dialog({
autoOpen: true,
width: 1000,
modal:false,
position:['middle',50],
resizable:false,
});

$('#dialog_graph2').click(function(){
$('#dialog-graph2').dialog('close');
return false;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a function for the close event of your dialog, i.e.:

```
$('#dialog-graph2').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 1000,
    modal:false,
    position:['middle',50],
    resizable:false,
    close: function(){
        document.equipmentIDN_form.equipmentIDN_direct.focus();
    }
});
```

This must do the work, but for elegance, I might use JQuery style intead of "pure" JavaScript, like this:

```
$('#equipementIDN_direct').focus();
```

But previously, add the id attribute (equipementIDN_direct) to your input text box.

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that when you open modal dialog last focused element is being saved save and back when dialog is closed (JQ UI 1.11) See example:    `http://jsfiddle.net/przemcio/9sxrvm95/`    I see that you have `autoOpen: true` then the dialog will be opened when a page will be loaded and in this specific situation proposition of Pispirulito is valid.